# Change Add to cart button text in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using Drupal 7 and Ubercart 3. I want to change the text for the button "Add to cart", how can I achieve this?

Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [string overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module is handy for these kind of things.

Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

> Features
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you
>     need a few easy text changes.